Regression Model
I am trying to run a regression model. For the model I weight the dependent variable (Y) by the number of residents in the city. Please, is it appropriate for me to also include the number of residents as an independent variable (X) in the model? Many thanks

Welcome to the site. Please give a little more detail about your research question and variables in your model.

What is the DV? What are the IVs? Are some another city level and some at the individual level?

I am investigating the impact of neighbourhood socio-economic characteristics  age, occupation, ethnicity on number of casinos. Dependent variable is number of casinos/1000 persons.

If your data points are cities and an independent variable is something like average income or average number of children or average value of something else whose value is assigned to each person within the city, then you should avoid mistaking the mean squared error in regression for an estimate of the variance of income or of the number of children of whatever the response variable is, because it does not take into account the variability within each city.

@MichaelHardy, I am not sure how this relates to the original question I asked.

afaict the natural model is built around $\log (\text{casino_count}) = \beta_0  + \text{av_age} \beta_a \ldots + \log (\text{population})  \beta_{p}$. Either fix $\beta_p$ to 1 (make it an offset) or 'include it in the regression' by estimating a coefficient for it. Finally fix an appropriate distribution for $\text{casino_count}$. Not sure why you'd also want to weight, tbh.

I could see it being appropriate. Suppose you have the following hypothesis: Larger cities, in terms of total population, have a lower murder rate.
You would calculate the murder rate by dividing by the total population (murders/population). However, you would still predict the murder rate using the total population as an independent variable.
I do wonder if a better modeling strategy is to predict the total number of murders based on the population, but there is something nice about how explicit it is to predict the murder rate that is of interest.
HOWEVER it could also make less sense to regress on the city population. If part of the reason you do not have access to the dependent variable (why you need to predict it instead of just look it up) is that you do not have access to the population at the time when you want to make the prediction, then you have an issue with missing data, possibly missing in a way that is intractable.

For your example, a poisson regression with offset is the thing. Somewhere there is a  be used both for predictor and offsetquestion about if same variable then can, answer is yes
